# Issue with real-time messaging in Flutter using Socket.IO

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I am a Flutter beginner implementing real-time messaging using Socket.IO in my app. The issue I'm facing is that sent messages are not displayed on the Flutter page, until I leave it and comeback to it. I have four events on my backend, including loading messages, signaling new messages, and emitting sent messages. However, the displayed message only appears after leaving and returning to the page.

I've implemented the Socket.IO events and ensured the proper setup. I expected the sent messages to be immediately displayed on the Flutter page without needing to leave and return. I've tried all the implementation of streambuilder, but the issue persists.
Here's my Flutter implementation:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:pfetest01app/services/controllers/artisan_controller.dart';
import 'package:pfetest01app/services/controllers/client_controller.dart';
import 'package:pfetest01app/services/controllers/fournisseur_controller.dart';

// ignore: library_prefixes
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

class MessageView extends StatefulWidget {
  final int idDestinataire;
  final int idDestinateur;
  final String? messageAchat;

  const MessageView({
    super.key,
    required this.idDestinateur,
    required this.idDestinataire,
    this.messageAchat,
  });

  @override
  State<MessageView> createState() => _MessageViewState();
}

class _MessageViewState extends State<MessageView> {
  List _messages = [];
  final _messageStreamController = StreamController<List>();
  Stream get messagesStream => _messageStreamController.stream;
  final TextEditingController _messageInputController = TextEditingController();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  late IO.Socket _socket;
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var idConversation;
  dynamic destinataire;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initChat();
    if (widget.messageAchat != null) {
      setState(() {
        _messageInputController.text = widget.messageAchat!;
      });
    }
  }

  initChat() async {
    _initSocketIO();
    joinRoom(widget.idDestinateur, widget.idDestinataire);
    getDestinataire();
  }

  void _initSocketIO() {
    final String chatApi = dotenv.env['CHAT_API']!;

    // Connexion au serveur Socket.IO
    _socket = IO.io(
        chatApi,
        IO.OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket'])
            .enableAutoConnect()
            .enableForceNewConnection()
            .build());

    // Écoute des événements
    _socket.onConnect((_) {
      log('Connecté');
    });

    _socket.on('newMessage', (data) {
      // Manipulez le nouveau message reçu
      setState(() {
        _messages.add(data);
      });
      // _messageStreamController.sink.add(_messages);
      // other.sink.add(data);
      log('ENouveau message: $data');
      log('hi');
      log('Last element: ${_messages.last}');
    });

    _socket.on('loadMessages', (data) {
      // Manipulez les messages reçus du serveur
      setState(() {
        _messages = data;
      });
      _messageStreamController.add(data);
      // log('Messages chargés: $data');
    });

    _socket.on('connectedRoom', (data) {
      // Manipulez la salle de conversation connectée
      log('Salle de conversation connectée: $data');

      setState(() {
        idConversation = data;
      });
    });

    _socket.onDisconnect((reason) => log('disconnected $reason'));
  }

  void joinRoom(int user1, int user2) {
    // Envoyer un message 'joinRoom' au serveur
    _socket.emit('joinRoom', {
      'id_user1': user1,
      'id_user2': user2,
    });
  }

  void leaveConversation(conversationId) {
    // Envoyer un message 'leaveConversation' au serveur
    _socket.emit(
        'leaveConversation', {'id_conversation': int.parse(conversationId)});
  }

  // void nouveauMessage() {
  //   _socket.on('newMessage', (data) {
  //     // Manipulez le nouveau message reçu
  //     setState(() {
  //       _messages.add(data);
  //     });
  //     _messageStreamController.sink.add(_messages);
  //     log('Nouveau message: $data');
  //   });
  // }

  void sendMessage() {
    // Envoyer un message 'sendMessage' au serveur
    log("conversation id : $idConversation");
    _socket.emit('sendMessage', {
      'id_conversation': int.parse(idConversation),
      'id_destinateur': widget.idDestinateur,
      'message': _messageInputController.text,
    });
    _messageInputController.clear();
  }

  getDestinataire() async {
    dynamic data;

    try {
      data = await ArtisanController.getOneArtisan(widget.idDestinataire);
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
    if (data == null) {
      try {
        data = await ClientController.getOneClient(widget.idDestinataire);
      } catch (e) {
        log(e.toString());
      }
    }
    if (data == null) {
      try {
        data = await FournisseurController.getOneFournisseur(
            widget.idDestinataire);
      } catch (e) {
        log(e.toString());
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      destinataire = data;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose(); // Dispose the scroll controller
    _messageInputController.dispose(); // Dispose the text input controller
    leaveConversation(idConversation);
    _socket.disconnect();
    _messageStreamController.close();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            '${destinataire?.nom.toLowerCase()} ${destinataire?.prenom.toLowerCase()}',
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24),
          ),
          toolbarHeight: 60,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _socket.disconnect();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new, color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        body: destinataire != null
            ? Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: messagesStream,
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return const Text('Error loading messages');
                      } else {
                        final messages = snapshot.data;
                        return ListView.builder(
                          reverse: true,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                          itemCount: messages?.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final message =
                                messages![messages.length - 1 - index];
                            bool isSelf = message['id_destinateur'] ==
                                widget.idDestinateur;
                            return Wrap(
                              key: ValueKey(message['id_message'].toString()),
                              alignment: isSelf
                                  ? WrapAlignment.end
                                  : WrapAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Card(
                                  color: isSelf
                                      ? Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight
                                      : Colors.white,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      crossAxisAlignment: isSelf
                                          ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                                          : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(message['contenu']),
                                        Text(
                                          DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(
                                            DateTime.parse(
                                                message['date_message']),
                                          ),
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .bodySmall,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  )),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 16,
                    ),
                    child: SafeArea(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: _messageInputController,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Type your message here...',
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (_messageInputController.text
                                  .trim()
                                  .isNotEmpty) {
                                sendMessage();
                              }
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            : const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
      );
}
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance!